# Regex string contains at least one character

Tags: regex

I have a special code which is always 7 characters. The first 3 character must always contain a letter [A-Za-z].

Ex: `12**A**5667` or `**A**2156903` OR `2**A**14312`

I know I can do it with `^\d{2}[A-Za-z]\d{4}|[A-Za-z]\d{2}\d{4}|\d[A-Za-z]\d{5}$`
but is there a way that I can simplify this code with look-ahead function or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(?=\d{0,2}[A-Za-z])[\dA-Za-z]{3}\d{4}$
```

It uses a lookahead to ensure that there is a letter at most two digits away from the start. Then, it starts the line again and it checks that it has 3 digits or letters at the beginning followed by 4 digits.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. When I put a dollar sign at the end ^(?=\d{0,2}[A-Za-z])[\dA-Za-z]{3}\d{4}$ , it will NOT BE MATCHING

Comment: @tomsam I forgot the `$`.

Answer (score 2):

You could find useful something like this:

```
\d{0,2}[A-Za-z]\d{4,6}
```

And then to check if the length is your expected length

Comment: thanks for the regex. It works fine, but I think lookahead function will work better for my case